# is this set closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

if we take set A={$(1/n, 1-1/n):n\in N$}, is this set closed? I think no because it doesn't equal it's set of limit points.I think set of limit points of this set is empty so, this is not an closed set.what do you think?

Comment: (0,1) is limit point ,which is not in A, hence A is not closed.

Comment: “$A$ is closed” does _not_ mean that “$A$ equals its set of limit points”.  It means “$A$ **contains** its set of limit points”.

Comment: so it is closed right?because it's set of limit points are  0(empty set), so A contains empty set.so it is closed right?

Comment: As @Pratik showed in a comment, the set of limit points of $A$ is not empty.